# How to change the background color of one row instead of all rows?

Tags: jquery

I have a table row with class `trhlite`

```
"<tr class='trhlite'; bgcolor='".$color."'; onMouseOver=\"this.bgColor='pink';\"   
onMouseOut=\"this.bgColor='".$color."';\" id=\"row"."\">";
```

Onclick of a button in each row, it must change the color of the entire row.

But my jQuery changes for all rows in the table:

```
var id = id;

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $this->address .'feedback/postflag'?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "id=" + id,
    success: function (data) {
        var index = parseFloat(id);
        // alert(index);            
        $(".trhlite").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
})
```

How should I change it so that it changes a particular row only?

Comment: You say ONE row is like that, but please show us the code for the other rows...

Comment: Plz tell me how to call above ajax function?

Comment: hi,below is the one I'm calling javascript"<td width='3';class='stylecontent';>"."<input type='button' class='btnstyle' Value='POST' onclick=\"setpost('".$record['id']."')\">". "</td>";

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".trhlite .buttonSelector").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".trhlite").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Didn't test, but should work. (Replace `.buttonSelector` with the class of the button, or use the semantic term (such as: `input`).

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, using `$(".trhlite")` as a selector, will match all elements that have a class of trhlite. To make it work with only the one row, you'll need a way to uniquely identify which row was affected, and then access that one to change its background!

Answer (score 0):

$(".trhlite").css("background-color","yellow");
means any object with class trhlite will have a bgcolor yellow.

Try adding unique values to your classes each row like trhlite1 trhlite2 or something else so you can change bgcolors individually.

I would love to help more but I can't with the information you provided.

Maybe adding all of the js code would help.

Comment: hi,I am addding my js.I tried with id of the row,it never works,    function setpost(id){

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it may what you want to implement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("someTableSelector").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#000000');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add semicolons between attributes in HTML. But your problem is possibly because all rows share the same ID, should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example: [jsfiddle.net/ntvYq/](http://jsfiddle.net/ntvYq/)

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have pass selector in function and use like

```
function change_bg(this)
{
  $(this +".trhlite").css("background-color","yellow");
}
```